# My Ifstream reference is not working although it did in similar previous function

Tags: c++, function, io, pass-by-reference, void

I have a file I want to continue calling on in different functions in my program. It worked fine as a reference in the **shiftText** function but when I repeated the reference in the next function, all that returns is 0,

Can I get a small hint at something I am missing perhaps to make it behave this way? Thanks!

(PS there's definitely a lot of 'fat' in this that I have included for testing purposes only)
I will eventually return the value of "e" into the shiftText function if you were curious why that's there :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
#include <cctype>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void inputfile(ifstream &masterfile) // ask for file name
{
    string filename;
    cout << "Please enter the name and extension of your file " << endl;
    cin >> filename;
    masterfile.open(filename);
    if (!masterfile)
    {
        cout << "warning: cannot open file" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
}

int findShift(ifstream &file, int counter[]) // find most used char
{
    char ch;
    int code;
    while (file.get(ch))
    {
        code = static_cast<int>(ch);
        cout << code << " ";
        counter[code]++;
    }
    int max, min;
    int indexMax, indexMin;
    max = counter[65];
    indexMax = 65;
    min = counter[65];
    indexMin = 65;
    for (int i = 66; i <= 122; i++)
    {
        if (counter[i] > max)
        {
            max = counter[i];
            indexMax = i;
        }
        if (counter[i] < min)
        {
            min = counter[i];
            indexMin = i;
        }
    }
    cout << endl
         << "Most frequent was " << indexMax;
    return indexMax;
}

void shiftText(ifstream &file) // this is where my program skips over my ifstream reference
{
    char ch;
    int code;
    while (file.get(ch))
    {
        code = static_cast<int>(ch);
        cout << code << " ";
    }
}

char stopFlashing() // for sanity
{
    char reply;
    cout << endl
         << "Press q (or any other key) followed by 'Enter' to quit: ";
    cin >> reply;
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int counter[256] = {0};
    ifstream file;

    inputfile(file);

    int e = findShift(file, counter);

    shiftText(file);
    cout << endl << " " << file << " " << endl; // for testing, a zero is returned
    stopFlashing();
}
```

Comment: you reached end of file in `findShift`, you have to rewind to beginning. the fact that you're using same object also means that you retain same state

Comment: THANK YOU. I'm a sleep deprived dummy.

Comment: Side note: Don't try to open a file stream twice without closing it in between. The second open will automatically fail.

Answer (score 0):

In function `findShift` you loop over the file. In function `shiftText` you are trying to do the same. However, the file is already at its end. Before calling `shiftText` you should rewind the file by using [seekg](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg):

```
file.seekg(0, std::ios_base::beg)
```